# convert unix file

Tags: c#

I received some large text files with a Unix line break (I think). I usually open small files in my text editor and save them as PC text file but these files are too big for this approach. So I thought I write a little C# program.

I usually use something like this:

```
using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(@"D:\bla.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] items = line.Split('|');
```

but the Unix line break causes problem. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Christian

Comment: Can you open the files in Visual Studio? If so, it should pop up its "convert line endings" dialog.

Comment: The problem might be unrelated to unix newlines. So, what problems are you actually having ?

Comment: I can open the files in text editors like textpad. when I try to save them everything crashes (VS has problems too). i pressume it has to do with the size of the files 800MB - 18GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix line breaks shouldn't cause any problems for `TextReader.ReadLine` - it's specifically designed to cope with any line break. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx):

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return (0x000d), a line feed (0x000a), a carriage return followed by a line feed, Environment.NewLine, or the end of stream marker. The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed. The returned value is null if the end of the input stream has been reached.

This flexible definition includes the normal Unix line break of "\n".

I suspect your problem lies elsewhere. You haven't actually said what problems you believe are caused by the Unix line breaks. What's going wrong at the moment?

Comment: The final aim is to bulk insert the data - '\n' causes problems during bulk insert. My C# code also fails ...

Comment: @csetzkorn: But if you're using TextReader.ReadLine, you won't be seeing the `\n` to start with. Are you sure it's not an encoding issue instead? When you say your C# code fails, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [ToFroWin](http://sysd.org/stas/node/34).